# Minecraft Forge event.entity vs event.player

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am new to Minecraft modding and I noticed that sometimes, when changing the players motion, they use

```
EntityPlayer player = event.player;
```

and other times they use as below:

```
EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer) event.entity;
```

What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: One uses implicit casting, the other uses explicit casting to an EntityPlayer object.

Comment: In first one, you are getting the EntityPlayer directly from event object and in second one, you are typecasting entity to EntityPlayer. For more on typecasting you can read here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html

Comment: Have you tried to understand (a) how casting works and (b) the types between which they are casting?

Comment: I get that, but should I use one at times and not the other? What is best?